# how to clear dataGridView rows previous data before adding now data in dynamically....?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

```
 for(int c =1;c<=author.books.count;c++)             
 {

  string author = author.name.ToString();

  string author = author.book_name.ToString();
  string author = author.published_year.ToString();

  string[] row = new string[]{author, book_name, published_year};
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
 }
```

this my code(similarly)........i am getting data from one XML file. my problem was when i select one author its giving data in gridview in windows_form.after that if i select one more author comming data is append to previews data. i want to display only current selected author data.

i tried like:

```
      dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

when i am put this code in pgm before for loop its not even giving any data in "GridView" through-out pgm.

i tried like:

```
     if (this.dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
      {
          this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
      }
     else
     {
       this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
     }
```

same way like above its not displaying any data.

please help me.................

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection` for such cases.

Comment: can you give an example code...........i am new to c#

Answer (score 2):

You are clearing rows if your `datasource = null`. Which means you will not clear rows if some datasource is already assigned. Which is your case.

so you should do it like this. No need of if statement.

Remove this statement

```
 if (this.dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
```

and your code should look like this

```
      this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
      this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

This is the proper way of clearing rows.

Answer (score 0):

read the xml into dataTable and bind the table with the datagridview. You dont need to clear the row content in this case.

Otherwise u can use `datagridview.Rows.RemoveAt(index)` or `datagridview.Rows.Remove(row)`

Comment: i used below loop befor for loop. even its adding to previous data........                                                                        for (int row_count = dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row_count >= 0; row_count--)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row_count-1);                    
                }

Comment: if u r binding the datagridview into something above statement wont work